# jquery not working in IE,EDGE and FIREFOX but working in CHROME

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

i have a form

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <div class="commentdiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
    <textarea style="" name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;"class="submit">
      comment
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is my javascript

```
$(document).on('click','.submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $post = $(this);
    var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
    var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();

    $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").next(".comments");

    //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
    var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
        comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };
   //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
   var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
         comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };

   $.ajax({
   url:'comments.php',  
   data:dataString,
   success:function(){
 $commentsec.append('<p class="written"><a href="users.php?id= <?php echo $id3; ?>"><b style=color:black !important>'+username2+'</b> </a>'+comment2+"</p>"+'<div class="dropdown"><img src="ellipsis.png" class="dots"><div class="dropdown-content"><br><p  class="delete" data-delete=<?php echo $commentid; ?>">delete</p></div></div>');
     $(" #comment").val("");   
   }
   });
});
```

i want that whenever a user clicks on this button an alert should pop up and that comment should append to this form that user has written now this whole code is working fine in google chrome but does not work in firefox chrome or  microsoft edge i dont know what  to do

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: nothing i think that click event is not working @Sv443

Comment: Open the browser's console before you make the request, then check for any errors which appear when your code runs

Comment: Like @RoryMcCrossan said, please open the console (F12 on most browsers) and tell us which error(s) get(s) thrown

Comment: add error handler to the Ajax call too